# Adding new field and populating with converted heights from another field using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy

My assignment is to create 3 shapefiles for three positions in a hockey shapefile and select these by a specific country (Sweden). After creating these files I need to add two fields and populate them. I have a height field in ft/inches and a weight field in kg. I need to populate the two new fields with height in cm and weight in lbs. I have gotten all the way to through adding the two fields without issue but cannot seem to figure out how to convert and add to new field.

```
import os
import arcpy


# # set workplace environment, input folder and results folder
arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\GEOG485\GEOG485_Lesson3\project3_2021'
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
# Variables for analysis
Country_Of_Interest = """ "CNTRY_NAME" = 'Sweden'"""
Position_Of_Interest = ['C','LW','RW']
# SHapefiles
Players = "nhlrosters.shp"
Countries = "Countries_WGS84.shp"
outPath = r'C:\GEOG485\GEOG485_Lesson3\project3_2021'
total_cm = 0
tot_inches = 0
# Make Feature Layers of both files
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Countries,'Countries_Layer',Country_Of_Interest)

    #For Loop through List
outputList = []
for x in Position_Of_Interest:
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(Players,'Player_Layer',""" "primaryPos" = '{}' """.format(x))
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management('Player_Layer','WITHIN','Countries_Layer')
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion('Player_Layer', outPath ,'Sweden_{}'.format(x))
    fc = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses("Sweden*.shp")
    #print(outputList)
for x in outputList:
    arcpy.AddField_management(x,'height_cm','TEXT')
    arcpy.AddField_management(x,'weight_kg','FLOAT')     

   
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor('Sweden_C.shp', ["height","height_cm"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        a = input("height")
        Height = a.split(',')
        ft = int(Height[0])
        inches = int(Height[1])
        cmeters = (12*ft + inches)*2.54
        tot_inches += (12*ft + inches)        
        row[1] = row[0] * 2.54 
        cursor.updateRow(row)
            
print("End")
```

Comment: Using an update cursor is fine but the Calculate Field tool would do it with less code.

Comment: What's the point of setting all those variables in the `row` loop if you never use them for anything?

Comment: the point is, that is where the code breaks down for me, I don't know how to code to convert the values in one field and populate another field. Especially since the first field is TEXT because of the "' in ft/inches. I have a text field (height) I need to convert to cm from ft/inches and then I need that conversion to populate a new field called height_cm.